# What is wrong with my logic for Project Euler 71?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now I am trying to solve [Project Euler 71](http://projecteuler.net/problem=71).

> Consider the fraction, n/d, where n and d are positive integers. If
>   n
>
> If we list the set of reduced proper fractions for d ≤ 8 in ascending
>   order of size, we get:
>
> 1/8, 1/7, 1/6, 1/5, 1/4, 2/7, 1/3, 3/8, 2/5, 3/7, 1/2, 4/7, 3/5, 5/8,
>   2/3, 5/7, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 6/7, 7/8
>
> It can be seen that 2/5 is the fraction immediately to the left of
>   3/7.
>
> By listing the set of reduced proper fractions for d ≤ 1,000,000 in
>   ascending order of size, find the numerator of the fraction
>   immediately to the left of 3/7.

### The Current Code:

```
from fractions import Fraction
import math

n = 428572
d = 1000000

x = Fraction(3,7)

best = Fraction(0)

while d > 1:
    if Fraction(n,d) >= x:
        n-=1
    else:
        y = Fraction(n,d)
        if (x - y) < (x - best):
            best = y
        d -= 1
        n = int(math.ceil(d*0.428572))

print(best.denominator)
```

### Explanation:

```
from fractions import Fraction
import math
```

Needed for Fractions and math.ceil.

```
n = 428572
d = 1000000
```

These two variables represent the `n` and `d` stated in the original problem. The numbers start out this way because this is a slightly bigger representation of `3/7` (will be converted to Fraction later).

```
x = Fraction(3,7)

best = Fraction(0)
```

x is just a quick reference to `Fraction(3,7)` so I don't have to keep typing it. `best` is used to keep track what fraction is closest to `3/7` but still left of it.

```
while d > 1:
```

If `d <= 1` and `n` has to be less than `1` what is the point of checking? Stop check then.

```
if Fraction(n,d) >= x:
    n-=1
```

If the fraction ends up being bigger than or equal to `3/7` it isn't to the left of it, so keep subtracting from `n` till it is to the left of `3/7`.

```
    else:
        y = Fraction(n,d)
        if (x - y) < (x - best):
        best = y
```

If it is to the left of `3/7` see if `3/7` minus `best` or `y` (which is equal to the fraction we need to check) is closer to 0. The one closer to zero will be the least left, or closest to `3/7`.

```
        d -= 1
        n = int(math.ceil(d*0.428572))
```

Regardless of whether best changes or not, the denominator needs to be changed. So subtract one from the denominator and set n the Fraction(n,d) slightly greater (added extra ceil method to make sure it is greater!) than `3/7` to prune the test space.

```
print(best.denominator)
```

Finally print what the question wants.

### Note

Changing `d` to `8` and `n` to `4` (like the test case) gives the desired result of `5` for the denominator. Keeping it as is gives: `999997`.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: Not really. This is a well-structured question. Have some compensation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong:

> find the **numerator**

Apart from that, follow @Antimony's advice and learn about the Stern-Brocot tree, that's useful and fun.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the correct way to do things. You are supposed to use [the Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern-Brocot_tree). You shouldn't have to mess around with floating points at all.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful advice.

Answer (score 1):

Not to make you feel stupid. But your answer is perfectly correct, read the question again and change the last line to:

```
print( best.numerator )
```

Also, for the record there is a **MUCH** more efficient way of calculating this.